# Remove items from a dict if their key is not in a list - improve performance

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

I need to find the elements in a Python dictionary, whose keys are NOT present in a list.

I tried doing it in a very simple way:

```
import random

dict_dim = 100000
number_good_keys = 1000

complete_dict = {k: random.uniform(0,1) for k in range(dict_dim)}
keys_to_keep = [random.randrange(1, dict_dim, 1) for i in range(number_good_keys)]

keys_to_remove = [k for k in complete_dict.keys() if k not in keys_to_keep]
```

but the performance is horrible, considering the dict has around 250K elements, and the reference list 200K.
How can I do this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Change ``keys_to_keep`` from a list to set, which has O(1) time complexity on average

Comment: Maybe it will be faster, to create new dict? `{key : complete_dict[key] for key in keys_to_keep}`

Comment: Avoid  Python for loops with: `set(complete_dict.keys()) - set(keys_to_keep)`

Comment: you should iterate over `keys_to_keep` and check if the key is in the dictionary in O(1) time rather than check if the key is in the list in O(n) time